# Concatinating result with inner join

Tags: mysql

I wrote this piece of SQL to get movies with persones (role_id = 1 - is director). While movie has single director - all good, but extra rows with the same movie's name appear, when there is more than one directors.

```
SELECT
    m.name, 
    ps.name as director
FROM
    movies m
INNER JOIN participants p ON
    m.movie_id = p.movie_id
INNER JOIN persones ps ON
    ps.person_id = p.person_id AND
    p.role_id = 1    
ORDER BY m.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 10\G
```

For example

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    name: Film1
director: director1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
    name: Film1
director: director2
*************************** 3. row ***************************
    name: Film1
director: director3
*************************** 4. row ***************************
    name: Film2
director: director4
*************************** 5. row ***************************
    name: Film2
director: director5
*************************** 6. row ***************************
    name: Film2
director: director6
```

OK, i found group_concat for concatenate directors in single row

```
SELECT
    m.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(ps.name SEPARATOR ", ") as director
FROM
    movies m
INNER JOIN participants p ON
    m.movie_id = p.movie_id
INNER JOIN persones ps ON
    ps.person_id = p.person_id AND
    p.role_id = 1    
ORDER BY m.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 10\G
```

but i have unexpected result!

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    name: Film123
director: director1, someperson1, someperson3, ......, someperson18
```

Just one row with persons from another category (artists or smth). Even row with movie has name not the same as **ORDER BY m.updated_at DESC** must return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing with a `GROUP BY` you are using a group function but without grouping them

```
SELECT
    m.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(ps.name SEPARATOR ", ") as director
FROM
    movies m
INNER JOIN participants p ON
    m.movie_id = p.movie_id
INNER JOIN persones ps ON
    ps.person_id = p.person_id AND
    p.role_id = 1    
GROUP BY m.name /* or you can use the movie id column here*/
ORDER BY m.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

[**GROUP_CONCAT(expr)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

[**GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

**EDIT** Also make sure you do have `movie_id` column in your `movies` table

```
SELECT
    m.movie_id ,
    m.international_name AS o_name,
    m.description AS description,
    m.name AS name,
    m.covers AS covers,
    m.YEAR AS YEAR,
    m.updated_at AS added,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ps.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS director
FROM
    movies AS m
INNER JOIN  movies_genres AS mgen ON
    (m.movie_id = mgen.movie_id)
INNER JOIN participants p ON
    m.movie_id = p.movie_id
INNER JOIN persones ps ON
    ps.person_id = p.person_id AND
    p.role_id = 1 /* Directors */
WHERE
    m.hidden=0 AND
    mgen.genre_id = 6 AND

GROUP BY m.name
ORDER BY m.updated_at DESC
```

Comment: That is a small addition to other, more complex query. When i add this, MYSQL returns an error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'm.movie_id' in 'on clause'. Full query there: http://pastebin.com/U0WVMfC6

Comment: @Neka see my updated answer and also consider using [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with proper data set so it will be to diagnose the real problem

Comment: You actually have to group by all the columns you are selecting, so just grouping by m.name results in a faulty query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GROUP_CONCAT you have to use GROUP BY to create the groups.

```
SELECT
m.name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(ps.name SEPARATOR ", ") as director
FROM
    movies m
INNER JOIN participants p ON
    m.movie_id = p.movie_id
INNER JOIN persones ps ON
    ps.person_id = p.person_id AND
    p.role_id = 1    
GROUP BY m.movie_id,m.name
ORDER BY m.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```